# Internet Explorer, allowing cross domain forms

Tags: forms, cross-domain, internet-explorer-11

How do I get Internet Explorer to allow a form to post to an external domain.

I have a payment page that has a straight forward form

```
<FORM id="gateway_form" accept-charset="iso-8859-1" method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
...
</FORM>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 11 the browser freezes when I click the submit button.

I also have an alternative payment gateway setup (Global Iris) which works he same way, with  form that POSTS to the global gateway. That forms also crashes the browser when it is submitted.

When I put IE into compatibility mode it works fine.

I assume it's a security feature but I'm not sure what I can put onto the page, or the form, to turn it off.

Comment: There is nothing you need to do.  No browser prevents cross origin form submits.  There must be some other issue with your code or environment.

Comment: This is the only thing that is not working on the site though, there are other forms that submit fine. I've edited my question to show the <form> tag properly as I didn't indent it for code view before.